# Laplace's method: multivariate case with error term

Tags: integration, asymptotics, laplace-method

The $d$-dimensional case of [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method#Other_formulations) is usually given as something like

$$
\int_D h(\mathbf{x})e^{-Mf(\mathbf{x})}d\mathbf{x} \sim \Big(\frac{2\pi}{M}\Big)^{d/2}
\frac{h(\mathbf{x_0})e^{-Mf(\mathbf{x_0})}}{|Hess_f(\mathbf{x_0})|^{1/2}} \quad \text{ as }M\to\infty.
$$
Here $f$ and $h$ must be sufficiently smooth, and $f$ must attain the unique minimum $\mathbf{x_0}$ in the interior of $D$.

Ronald W. Butler's ["Saddlepoint Approximations with Applications"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/saddlepoint-approximations-with-applications/2F7AB9244B8B82035C10BF0FF54EF3F8) gives a similar result (formula 3.28), which also includes the relative error term $O(M^{-1}):$

$$
\int_D e^{-Mf(\mathbf{x})}d\mathbf{x} = \Big(\frac{2\pi}{M}\Big)^{d/2}
\frac{e^{-Mf(\mathbf{x_0})}}{|Hess_f(\mathbf{x_0})|^{1/2}}\big(1+O(M^{-1}) \big) \quad \text{ as }M\to\infty.
$$
However, this version doesn't include the additional factor $h(\mathbf{x})>0$.

My question is: is there a book or paper that proves or just quotes the multivariate Laplace approximation result, while also including the remainder term and the additional $h(\mathbf{x})$ factor? I.e. is the following true, under some assumptions:
$$
\int_D h(\mathbf{x})e^{-Mf(\mathbf{x})}d\mathbf{x} = \Big(\frac{2\pi}{M}\Big)^{d/2}
\frac{h(\mathbf{x_0})e^{-Mf(\mathbf{x_0})}}{|Hess_f(\mathbf{x_0})|^{1/2}}\big(1+O(M^{-1}) \big) \quad \text{ as }M\to\infty.
$$

My motivation is that [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/43863931.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3Af10bd757ee079ca8bf3d71107d4d8839&ab_segments=&origin=&initiator=&acceptTC=1) seems to use the above (very strong) form of Laplace's method, but I'm having trouble justifying it.

Comment: [here](https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:1058214/FULLTEXT01.pdf) they consider some asymptotic expansion for Laplaces method in one dimension. The do achieve a second order.See pp. 11.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Morse Lemma method is used here, and it gives the type of formula you seek.

**Asymptotic Approximation of Integrals**

Chapter 9, p. 483 Theorem 2

Author: Wong, Roderick

Publisher: Academic Press

ISBN: 0-12-762535-6, 978-0-12-762535-5

Date: 05/10/2014

Comment: The author of the book is [Roderick S. C. Wong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roderick_S._C._Wong).

Comment: @Gary Thanks. My library had the wrong author listed in its database!

Answer (score 0):

In Simon, B., Advanced Complex Analysis, Part B., AMS, 2015, pp. 174-175
Barry states and proves the following version of Laplace's method:

> Theorem: Let $f,g$ be real valued functions in $\mathbb{R}^d$ so that
>
> 1. $g_-:=\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d} g(x)>-\infty$,
> 2. $f\geq0$,
> 3. there is a unique $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $g(x_0)=g_-$,
> 4. for some $R>0$, $g_R:=\inf_{|x|\geq R}g(x)>g_-$,
> 5. for some $\alpha$, $\int e^{-\alpha g(x)}f(x)\,dx<\infty$,
> 6. $A=D^2g(x_0)$ is strictly positive definite,
> 7. $f(x_0)\neq0$,
> 8. $f,g$ are $C^\infty$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$.
>
> Then, if $Q(s):=\int e^{-sg(x)} f(x)\,dx$
> $$s^{d/2} e^{sg_-} Q(s)\sim (2\pi)^{d/2} f(x_0) \operatorname{det}(A)^{-1/2}\Big(1+\sum^\infty_{j=1}a_js^{-j}\Big)$$
> as $s\rightarrow\infty$.

The coefficients $a_j$ have explicit formulas in terms of derivative of $f$ and $g$ at $x_0$ (but quite complicated, *idem*). For $n=1$
$a_1=-\frac18\frac{g^{(4)}(x_0)}{(g^{(2)}(x_0))^2}+\frac{5}{24}\frac{(g^{(3)}(x_0))^2}{(g^{(2)}(x_0))^3}$

The proof given here is based on Morse's lemma.