# Generalization of Laplace's method

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Let $f$ and $g$ two real smooth functions, $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0) = 0$ and $f''(x_0) > 0$. Given $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, Laplace's method gives an equivalent of the form, as $t$ goes to $+\infty$,

$$
I_t := \int_a^b g(x) \exp{(-tf(x))} dx \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{t|f''(x_0)|}} g(x_0) \exp{(-tf(x_0))}
$$

I am looking for an extension of this result that gives a more general asymptotic expansion of the form

$I_t \exp{(tf(x_0))} = \sum_{k=1}^N a_k t^{-k/2} + o(t^{-N/2})$

where the coefficients $a_k$ depend on the coefficients of the Taylor expansions of $f$ and $g$.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tao’s notes should suffice: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/247b.1.07w/notes8.pdf Essentially, the idea is the same; for nondegenerate higher order derivatives, reduce the problem to asymptotics of $\int \exp(-tx^k) dx$ and Taylor expand to cover more general phase functions. Also see the chapter on oscillatory integrals in Stein’s Harmonic Analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the references, I will look into it. I wasn't sure whether results on oscillatory integrals could be used here since there is no complex term $\exp(itf(x))$.

Comment: Oh, I thought there was a complex phase in your original post. In any case, some techniques may still apply (namely passing from $\exp(tx^k)$ to the general case) but you should be careful to see where assumptions of the phase being real-valued is used in the resources above.

Comment: Here is another [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4691047/121671) with reference. Barry Simon's Complex Analysis Part B, has a proof based on Morse's lemma and further references and history.

Comment: I just found the result I was looking for in R. Wong's book (Asymptotic approximation of integrals), Theorem 3, p.495. the book is mentioned in the post you just sent me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.iii